# How to introduce Rust enum variants with a macro?

Tags: rust

I would like to use a Rust macro to introduce enum variants alongside "bespoke" ones. As a simple illustration:

```rust
macro_rules! make_beta {
    () => {Beta}
}

enum Greek {
    Alpha,
    make_beta! ()
}
```

My real goal is to have a family:

```rust
macro_rules! make_variants {
    ($($N:literal)+) => {
        $(
            Array$N([u8; $N]),
        )+
    }
}

enum Stuff {
    Empty,
    Something,
    make_variants! { 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 }
}
```

which has `Array1` through `Array8` in addition to "bespoke" variants. Unfortunately neither of these compiles: it complains about the exclamation mark [example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=351e0920199f23b76dd74ffd26bceb66).

How can I introduce enum variants with a macro?

Comment: Rust macros are not like C/C++ macros that can be used anywhere. They can only be used in certain situations, and enum variants are not included. So the compiler complains about `!` being unexpected because it doesn't expect a macro invocation in that position. (See the [Rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/macros.html#macro-invocation) for more details.)

Comment: Another reason why this won't work is that you can't build a new identifier with `Array$N` in a macro.

Comment: I don't really know your use case, but the [`smallvec` crate](https://crates.io/crates/smallvec) may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining the macro inside the `enum`, you could define the `enum` inside a macro like this:

```
macro_rules! enum_variants {
    ($name:ident {$($vals:tt)*} [$($tag:ident : $N:literal)+]) => {
        enum $name {
            $($vals)*
            $($tag([u8; $N])),+,
        }
    }
}

enum_variants! { Stuff {
        Empty,
        Something(i32),
    }
    [A1:1 A2:2 A3:3 A4:4 A5:5 A6:6 A7:7 A8:8]
}

fn main() {
    let x = Stuff::A3;
    let y = Stuff::Something(3);
}
```

UDPATE: Using the `paste` crate as mentioned by Frxstrem in the comments:

```
macro_rules! enum_variants {
    ($name:ident {$($vals:tt)*} [$($N:literal)+]) => {
        paste::item!{
            enum $name {
                $($vals)*
                $([<Array $N>]([u8; $N])),+,
            }
        }
    }
}

enum_variants! { Stuff {
        Empty,
        Something(i32),
    }
    [1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8]
}
```

Comment: Note you’ll have to explicitly use a notation like A1:1 A2:2 for each variant because you can’t join names in a macro unless you use the nightly feature ‘concat_idents!’

Comment: I believe `concat_idents!` wouldn't work either as that too is a macro in a variant position, which is the same problem. A crate like [`paste`](https://docs.rs/paste/0.1.12/paste/) could work, though.

Comment: Updated answer to use `paste`.